# PrimoPDF script error - twitter.com

Tags: script, print-to-pdf

When running PrimoPDF, I get the following script error:

```
An error has occurred in the script on this page.
Line: 0
Char: 0
Error: Script error
Code: 0
URL: http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js
```

If I ignore it, it seems to generate the PDF alright, but I'd like it not to come up anymore. Could anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for files containing "platform.twitter.com" and deleted the files that were found, all in "Temporary Internet Files" subfolders for various users of the PC. That stopped the script errors.

Dave Glow
Chelmsford, MA